# Ignore pinned tabs in Chrome when switching tabs by shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-tabs

When I have a pinned tab in Chrome on the left side of my open tabs, I want it to be ignored from <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> shortcuts.

Is there a way to enable this?